# Unmarshalling custom [32]byte type is returning zero value

Tags: go

I am attempting to unmarshal a custom/alias Hash of type [32]byte but the results are returning the zero value. The following code is just a snippet of what I am trying to do. In this snippet I am producing the json just to give an example but in my actual codebase it would be produced and read from another source. Here is the snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/json"
 )

 type Block struct {
     Key Hash `json:"hash"`
 }

 type Hash [32]byte

 func (h Hash) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
     return []byte(hex.EncodeToString(h[:])), nil
 }

 func (h Hash) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
     _, err := hex.Decode(h[:], data)
     return err
 }

 func main() {
     b := Block{sha256.Sum256([]byte("afasdfasfasfjiuoiuioupio"))}

     j, _ := json.Marshal(b)

     var unmarshalled Block
     err := json.Unmarshal(j, &unmarshalled)
     if err != nil {
         os.Exit(1)
     }

     fmt.Printf("%x\n", unmarshalled.Key)
     // prints out 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  }
```

Comment: Use a pointer receiver for the unmarshal method.

Comment: wow @MuffinTop, I can't believe I totally overlooked that. Stil can't wrap my head around why. I didn't use a pointer for MarshalText so I just assumed it would be the same for UnmarshalText. Would you mind posting an answer and shedding some light as to why a pointer was needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UnmarshalText method modifies the value `h`, not the value in the caller. Use a pointer receiver to modify the caller's value.

```
func (h *Hash) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
    _, err := hex.Decode(h[:], data)
    return err
}
```